# Going to chat.stackexchange.com takes me to Area 51? (2017)

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, regression

If I type chat.stackexchange.com into my browser, it resolves as area51.stackexchange.com.

The same happens if I click the chat link from the dropdown on a site, as well.

This just started within the last couple of minutes. I'm using Chrome, if that matters any.

Comment: also for chat.meta.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I broke it. I just unbroke it. Sorry!

Comment: Weren't you promoted to a manager role for good reason? Just stick with that, Okay? ... ;-)

Comment: So what's going on your door for this?

Comment: Thank you for unbreaking it! :)

Comment: @rene no kidding... haha.

Comment: So no aliens involved? Kind of disappointing. ;)

Comment: @Haney I know this is an old post, but I can barely contain my laughter at the word "unbroke".

Comment: Just a minor thing, your profile About Me isn't updated.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry updated.